# How to use different values for sort and display in DataTables 1.10

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I've upgraded to DataTables 1.10 and am having trouble using column.data or column.render to use different values for sort and display.

The data looks like:

```
[
    {
      "title":"Overview Report: (2014-07-12 11:49 - 2014-07-12 23:49)",
      "reportDateRangeMilliseconds":43200000,
      "DateRange":"12 hours"
   },
   {
      "title":"User Overview Report: (2014-07-12)",
      "reportDateRangeMilliseconds":86400000,
      "DateRange":"1 day"
   },
   {
      "title":"Activity Report: (2014-07-31 23:00 - 2014-08-03 00:00)",
      "reportDateRangeMilliseconds":176400000,
      "DateRange":"2 days, and 1 hour"
   }
]
```

I want to create one column that displays `DateRange` and sorts using `reportDateRangeMilliseconds`

I've tried:

```
$('#reportList').dataTable({
    "data" : reportData,    
    "columns" : [
        { "title" : "Report Name",
         "data" : "title"
        },
        { "title" : "Date Range",
          "data" : "reportDateRangeMilliseconds",
          "render" : {
             "display" : "DateRange"
          }
        }
    ]
})
```

But it returns the error:

> DataTables warning: table id=reportList - Requested unknown parameter
>   'reportDateRangeMilliseconds' for row 0. For more information about
>   this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

See http://jsfiddle.net/scottglew/pmpj9uyb/1/

I've also tried:

```
$('#reportList').dataTable({
    "data" : reportData,    
    "columns" : [
        { "title" : "Report Name",
         "data" : "title"
        },
        { "title" : "Date Range",
          "data" : {
              "sort" : "reportDateRangeMilliseconds",
              "display" : "DateRange"
          }
        }
    ]
})
```

Which doesn't return an error, but also doesn't sort correctly using the milliseconds value. See http://jsfiddle.net/scottglew/jrnou3p3/2/

I've also tried a range of other combinations but haven't had any joy. Can anyone save my sanity?

Answer (score 7):

I finally found a way to achieve this, by creating another hidden column for the milliseconds value, and then I pointed the `orderData` property of the 'Date Range' column to the hidden column.

```
$('#reportList').dataTable({
    "data" : reportData,    
    "columns" : [
        { "title" : "Report Name",
         "data" : "title"
        },
        { "title" : "Range In milliseconds",
          "data" : "reportDateRangeMilliseconds",
          "visible" : false
        },
        { "title" : "Date Range",
          "data" : "DateRange",
          "orderData" : [1]
        },
    ]
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/vxshL3ju/1/

But doesn't this defeat the purpose of the new "sort" and "display" properties introduced in DataTables 1.10?

Answer (score 2):

For my needs in a haml file in a Rails app, this is how I achieved viewing and sorting on a human readable distance (feet/meters when near, and miles/kilometers when > 1 mile) via a hidden distance column:

```
$('.water_supply table').DataTable({
  "order": [[3, "asc"]],
  "paging": true,
  "pageLength": 20,
  // Have the visible distance column (2) sort actually use the
  // (hidden) monotonic distance_in_miles column data (3rd)
  "columnDefs": [
      { "targets": [2],
        "visible": true,
        "orderData": [3]
      },
      { "targets": [3],
        "visible": false,
      }
    ]
});
```

Comment: This ended up being really helpful to me, it was much easier than installing sorting extensions. +1